# Istio Ingress Gateway using SDS failing due to credential Name

Tags: gateway, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I'm trying to follow the instructions from: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/secure-ingress/sds/

However, when trying to create the Ingress Gateway, I am getting some form of validation error.

Much googling hasn't found me anything!

```
Error from server: error when creating "STDIN": admission webhook "pilot.validation.istio.io" denied the request: error decoding configuration: YAML decoding error: selector:
  istio: ingressgateway
servers:
- hosts:
  - httpbin.example.com
  port:
    name: https
    number: 443
    protocol: HTTPS
  tls:
    credentialName: httpbin-credential
    mode: SIMPLE
 unknown field "credentialName" in v1alpha3.Server_TLSOptions
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is specifically

> unknown field "credentialName" in v1alpha3.Server_TLSOptions

The feature you're trying to use is only available in [Istio 1.1](https://istio.io/about/notes/1.1/); you'll need to upgrade to the 1.1 series (probably 1.1.2 or 1.1.3 to take advantage of the security fixes) to get at this.

Comment: Yup that has resolved this issue. There really should be some note in the documentation that this is a feature for the more recent versions!